# Pickle a frozen dataclass that has __slots__

Tags: python, pickle, slots, python-dataclasses

How do I pickle an instance of a frozen dataclass with `__slots__`? For example, the following code raises an exception in Python 3.7.0:

```
import pickle
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass(frozen=True)
class A:
  __slots__ = ('a',)
  a: int

b = pickle.dumps(A(5))
pickle.loads(b)
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 3, in __setattr__
dataclasses.FrozenInstanceError: cannot assign to field 'a'
```

This works if I remove either the `frozen` or the `__slots__`. Is this just a bug?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Starting in Python 3.10.0, this works but only if you specify the slots via `slots=True` in the dataclass decorator. It does not work, and probably will never work, with `__slots__` manually specified.

```py
import pickle
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass(frozen=True, slots=True)
class A:
  a: int

b = pickle.dumps(A(5))
pickle.loads(b)  # A(a=5)
```

Answer (score 15):

The problem comes from `pickle` using the `__setattr__` method of the instance when setting the state of the slots.

The default `__setstate__` is defined in `load_build` in [`_pickle.c` line 6220](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Modules/_pickle.c#L6220).

For the items in the state dict, the instance `__dict__` is updated directly:

```
 if (PyObject_SetItem(dict, d_key, d_value) < 0)
```

whereas for the items in the slotstate dict, the instance's `__setattr__` is used:

```
if (PyObject_SetAttr(inst, d_key, d_value) < 0)
```

Now because the instance is frozen, `__setattr__` raises `FrozenInstanceError` when loading.

To circumvent this, you can define your own `__setstate__` method which will use `object.__setattr__`, and not the instance's `__setattr__`.

The [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html#frozen-instances) give some sort of warning for this:

> There is a tiny performance penalty when using frozen=True: `__init__()` cannot use simple assignment to initialize fields, and must use `object.__setattr__()`.

It may also be good to define `__getstate__` as the instance `__dict__` is always `None` in your case. If you don't, the `state` argument of `__setstate__` will be a tuple `(None, {'a': 5})`, the first value being the value of the instance's `__dict__` and the second the slotstate dict.

```
import pickle
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass(frozen=True)
class A:
    __slots__ = ('a',)
    a: int

    def __getstate__(self):
        return dict(
            (slot, getattr(self, slot))
            for slot in self.__slots__
            if hasattr(self, slot)
        )

    def __setstate__(self, state):
        for slot, value in state.items():
            object.__setattr__(self, slot, value) # <- use object.__setattr__


b = pickle.dumps(A(5))
pickle.loads(b)
```

I personally would not call it a bug as the pickling process is designed to be flexible, but there is room for a feature enhancement. A revision of the pickling protocol could fix this in future. Unless I am missing something and aside of the *tiny performance penalty*, using `PyObject_GenericSetattr` for all the slots might be a reasonable fix?

Comment: I updated the previously deleted answer. It all boils down to creating your own `__setstate__` method to avoid a call to the instance's `__setattr__`.

Comment: do you know why it works if the class doesn't have slots? does it not use setattr to initialize in that case?

Comment: @Arne Good point, I just had a look in the source code of `pickle` and it seems that the other attributes are dealt with by modifying `__dict__` directly whereas the slots use `__setattr__`. I'll take a deeper look and update.

Comment: I have [reported](https://bugs.python.org/issue36424) this issue and recommended your workaround to the Python bug tracker. Hopefully, it will make it into the standard library.

Comment: @drhagen Great, I'll try to compile with `PyObject_GenericSetattr` when I'll get a chance. Fingers crossed!

Comment: Just for anyone looking for a little more detail, see https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0307/

Comment: Just to note: the same issue appears to arise when using Python's multiprocessing library.

Answer (score 0):

If you only need the class to be hashable, you can force generate `__hash__` function with `unsafe_hash=True` option. You will not get the immutability guarantee, but immutability in python is impossible anyways.

[Relevant python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html#module-contents) states:

> Although not recommended, you can force `dataclass()` to create a `__hash__()` method with `unsafe_hash=True`. This might be the case if your class is logically immutable but can nonetheless be mutated. This is a specialized use case and should be considered carefully.

```py
import pickle
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass(unsafe_hash=True)
class A:
    __slots__ = ('a',)
    a: int

b = pickle.dumps(A(5))
hash(pickle.loads(b))  # works and can hash!
```